# Memory leak from Promoted class of QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: qt, qt5

I am promoting the QDoubleSpinBox class as i want to catch the mouseDoubleClick Event.

This is the Promoted class.

```
class SumDoubleBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit SumDoubleBox(QWidget* parent = nullptr);   
    void setSingleStep(double val);
    double singleStep() const;
    void stepBy(int steps) override;
protected:
    virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e) override;         
public slots:       
    void setZero();
    void setOne();

signals:
    int signalUndoRedo();

private:
    double m_defaultStep = 1.0;
    double m_CurrentStep;
    bool m_stepUp;
};



SumDoubleBox::SumDoubleBox(QWidget* parent) : QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
{
    SumLineEdit* lineEdit = new SumLineEdit(this);
    setLineEdit(lineEdit);
    setMinimum(0.0);
    setMaximum(99999.0);
}
```

Since i am creating a pointer in the Constructor of the SumDoubleBox Class.

```
  SumLineEdit* lineEdit = new SumLineEdit(this);
```

Do i need to Explicitly delete this in the Destructor ?

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
The Defination of the SumLineEdit class.

```
class SumLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SumLineEdit(QWidget* parent = nullptr) {   };
protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
};


void SumLineEdit::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        selectAll();
        event->accept();
        return;
    }
    QLineEdit::mouseDoubleClickEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've parented the new lineedit to the SumDoubleBox, it should get deleted with its parent.

There is, however, a more Qt-centric way to handle this case that I would strongly recommend you use or at least look into: Installing an event filter on the built-in line edit and handling the events for it. I've made many spinbox variants, and this approach usually works out best:

```
SumDoubleBox::SumDoubleBox( QWidget *parent ) :
    QDoubleSpinBox( parent )
{
    lineEdit()->installEventFilter( this );
}


bool SumDoubleBox::eventFilter( QObject *object, QEvent *event )
{
    if( object == lineEdit() && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick )
    {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>( event );
        if( mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
        {
            selectAll();
            event->accept();
            return true; //swallow the event
        }

    }
    return false; //let the event through to the lineedit
}
```

This makes the custom class entirely redundant. It's nice because inheritance is a big hammer that easily gets out of control as a codebase scales up, and if there are other simpler ways to achieve your goal, it's often worth considering.

Comment: After i install Event Filter the text data is not displayed in the Spinbox.

Comment: Oh I see. I had a bug. the eventfilter() should always return false by default so that the event goes through as usual, and only true in cases where you want it to block the event. My original snippet was not returning false for all the cases and thus blocking paint events. I actually compiled this edited version and it worked for me.